# Excel chart: Ordering by values (automatically)

Tags: excel, sorting, charts, bar-chart

I've got the following problem:

I need to order my values in bar chart from the highest to lowest:

[image]

I know that i can use pivot table and pivot chart, but it could be a bit complicated in the future.

Comment: umm... good luck? is there something you need help? can you show some code of what is not working?

Comment: I was just wondering if there's some code to order values in chart itself. I'm not able to change values in column a/b. This is just made up sheet. I was trying to write something, but it didn't work.

Comment: To achieve this, definitely you will need a sorted copy of your dataset as data source for your chart. And the horizontal axis can't be a date axis but must be a text axis, since the date values will be unordered if the values are sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to achieve this by using helper columns to order the data as you need.

1. Column C: Create a rank of the values using `RANK` function, for example: `=RANK(B2, $B$2:$B$16)`
2. Column D: Create an order column with numbers running from 1 to 15
3. Column E: Lookup each of the values in the order column using a combination of `MATCH` and `INDEX`, for example: `=INDEX($B$2:$B$16, MATCH(D2, $C$2:$C$16, 0))`
4. Column F: Lookup each of the dates using a similar approach as 3. wrap with a `TEXT` function to avoid excel ordering the dates in the graph, for example: `=TEXT(INDEX($A$2:$A$16, MATCH(E2, $C$2:$C$16, 0))|"dd mmmm yyyy")`
5. Update your graph to reference columns E and F
6. If all value cells aren't populated (as per your example) then you can wrap the formulas with an `IFERROR` to tidy it up

Example output below:

[image]

UPDATE:

To avoid issue when you have same value appearing you can add a countif to your rank function `RANK(B2, $B$2:$B$16) + COUNTIF($B$2:B2, B2)-1`

Comment: Thanks, it is working, but.. It gives me error when there are two and more same values. I tried to use it on my next chart, that i also need to order, but there are values like (8, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0). Can I somehow make function that says: "If this text already has value, find next?"

Comment: please see the update to avoid issue when same value appears, hope it helps

Comment: Fantastic! You don't know how much time you saved me :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If this completely covers your question would you mind to mark it as answered by clicking on the green arrow to the left of the answer? all the best

Comment: Done. But I unfortunately can not vote your answer. Don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @SamGilbert: Thanks for this solution. Works perfectly for me!

Answer (score 1):

Mine worked, but needed to change the reference to `E2` to `D2`.  Unsure if there is an error above...

3.Column E: Lookup each of the values in the order column using a combination of `MATCH` and `INDEX`, for example: `=INDEX($B$2:$B$16, MATCH(**D**2, $C$2:$C$16, 0))`

Answer (score 0):

With my scenario, I was having trouble wrapping my head around how to solve the issue of repeat values when using the ranking method.

I was able to achieve automatic ordering by creating a pivot table and ordering the data there.  The pivot table automatically re-orders itself as the data changes.